# Play 2 sound files at the same time, with different outputs

Tags: python, audio

I need to play 2 different sound files (.mp3 or .wav will be the format used) at the exact same time and have their sound be split into different outputs.

I have tried a few different things, like using the VLC library in Python but with no luck, I am completely stuck and back at 0. Any help or push in the right direction is extremely appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could try with `pydub` for the audio file and `sounddevice` for routing and the audio to different outputs.

Like for example:

```
import numpy as np
import sounddevice as sd
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import mediainfo
from scipy.io.wavfile import read

def play_audio(file, device):
    sample_rate = mediainfo(file)['sample_rate']
    audio = AudioSegment.from_file(file)
    audio.export("temp.wav", format="wav")
    _, data = read('temp.wav')
    data = data / np.iinfo(np.int16).max
    sd.play(data, device=device, samplerate=sample_rate)

print(sd.query_devices())
play_audio('file1.mp3', device=1)
play_audio('file2.mp3', device=2)
```